# Periodicity in the distribution of non-trivial zeros of the Riemann Zeta function

Tags: reference-request, riemann-zeta-function

Let us consider the Riemann Zeta function non-trivial zeros $\rho_{n}=\frac{1}{2} + i\gamma_{n}$.

Let us now consider the following sum:
$\tau (n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin(k)\sin(\gamma _{k})$

where:

$\gamma _{1}=14.1347251417346\ldots$

$\gamma _{2}=21.0220396387715\ldots$

$\gamma _{3}=25.0108575801456\ldots$

etc

This is the plot of $\tau (n)$ for $n$ between 1 and $10^4$:

[image: Plot 1]

My question is: does anyone know any articles where this periodicity is investigated?

Comment: Does $\rho_n$ denote the real part of the zero, or the zero itself?  If the former, (many more than) the first $10^n$ have real part 1/2; why not just write that?  If the latter, I don't understand the point of your first sentence.

Comment: @Stopple edited, thanks.

Comment: Can you include the figure in the post, not as a link?

Comment: @AmirSagiv: One needs 10 reputation points before being allowed to embed a figure. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.

Comment: Usually $\rho_n$ denotes the complex nontrivial zeros, written $\beta_n+i\gamma_n$; on the Riemann hypothesis $\beta_n=1/2$.  With this notation $\sin(\rho_n)$ and thus $\tau(n)$ are complex numbers, not real valued.  Either your $\tau(n)$ is actually the real part of your sum, or you are evaluating $\sin(\gamma_n)$, not $\sin(\rho_n)$.

Comment: @Stopple re-edited.

Comment: @Salvo I confirm your plot. There are other jumps, the next one between $10000<n<15000$ and other between $[50000,60000]$.  Perhaps $\sum_{k=1}^n e^{ikx+i\gamma_k}$ behaves as the sum considered by H. Montgomery in \emph{Ten Lectures on the Interface between Number Theory and Harmonic Analysis} p. 45--60.

Comment: @Salvo The figures of the partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^n e^{ik+i\gamma_k}$ are very similar to the ones in the book by Montgomery, I have done it for $1\le n\le 100000$.  Impressive.

Answer (score 1):

Assume

$$N(t)=\sum_{\Im(\rho)\le t} 1\tag{1}$$

is the non-trivial zeta zero counting function which counts the number of non-trivial zeta zeros in the upper-half plane with $\Im(\rho)\le t$.

---

The periodicity in

$$\tau(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(k) \sin (\gamma_k)\tag{2}$$

where $\gamma_k=\Im(\rho_k)$ is probably related to the following estimate of $N(t)$:

$$\tilde{N}(t)=\frac{t}{2 \pi} \left(\log\left(\frac{t}{2 \pi}\right)-1\right)+\frac{1}{2}\, \log(2 \pi)\tag{3}$$

---

Consider the following approximation to $\tau(n)$

$$\tilde{\tau}(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(k) \sin (\tilde{\gamma}_k)\tag{4}$$

where $\tilde{\gamma}_k$ refers to the root of $\tilde{N}(t)-k=0$ which is an estimate of the imaginary part of the $k^{th}$ zeta zero in the upper-half plane.

---

The following plot illustrates $\tau(n)$ defined in formula (2) above in blue and $\tilde{\tau}(n)$ defined in formula (4) above in orange.

[image: Illustration of formulas (2) and (4)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (2) for $\tau(n)$ (blue) and formula (4) for $\tilde{\tau}(n)$ (orange)

---

While $\tilde{\tau}(n)$ may not be a particularly good approximation of $\tau(n)$, Figure (1) above illustrates the oscillation in $\tau(n)$ seems to be related to the approximate regularity of $\Im(\rho_k)$.